# I need to know how to call backup of the same folder in codeignator?

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

I want to call to this `html1718` folder from the same domain name with 1718.

[image]

I have a site called http://lis.test.com/login/signin In that page there is a dropdown to select year.When I select 2017 from drop down it will direct to  http://lis.test.com/html1718/login/signin but it gives 
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
error. But the html1718 is the duplicate of html.Please help me to sort this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain what you've tried so far and what errors you're getting. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Dennis, I have given url on changing dropdown in jsfile.but it is not rediecting to the html18 folder home page

Comment: Your question came up in Review. I don't have the Codeigniter experience to be able to help you. Pretend you know nothing about this problem. In what way would you like someone else to explain it to you so you could understand it? Please edit all extra information into your question.